# Tunneling ssh via ssh with foxyproxy

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I'm tunneling over ssh with this command (under El Captain)

```
ssh -D port_number -N -C myusername@server.url
```

and enable foxyproxy on the browser. Everything seems to work just fine on the browser. However, on the terminal I keep getting messages of the form

> channel X: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed

for various channel numbers. I set `Tunnel yes` in `/etc/ssh_config` but that did not do anything. I repeat, things work despite the error messages.

Comment: Does this answer help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215262 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again. many things mixed up together. What are you trying to achieve? There are few things wrong, in your post:

- `Tunnel` option in `ssh_config` does not do anything related to the SOCKS5 Proxy, which is the command you are describing. It is related to VPN and "ethernet" (layer 2) tunnelling, which is initiated by `-w` option
- Port forwarding and SOCKS5 proxy (`-D`) is allowed by option `AllowTcpForwarding` in `sshd_config` on the server!
- If you would really want to user layer 2, forwarding, you need root login on the remote server.